# Splitting of VCF file of CSQ field in the INFO column to tabular format

Tags: python, r, bash, bioinformatics

VCF file will be having seven fixed columns and INFO column.
Chromosome, position, ID, ref, alt, qual, filter, and INFO column.
This INFO column will be having the variant related information.
In the INFO column CSQ field will be having multiple fields - 82 fields fixed with the delimeter "|" (piped). If no related information is present in that field. the pipe field will be empty.
Actually, for each variant the vcf file annotations provides multiple multiple transcripts information of that variant. So information of this CSQ field will be more than 82 fields.

```
##INFO=ID=CSQ,Type=String,Description="Consequence annotations. 
Format: Allele|Consequence|IMPACT|SYMBOL|Gene|Feature_type|Feature|BIOTYPE|EXON|INTRON|HGVSc|HGVSp|cDNA_position|CDS_position|Protein_position|Amino_acids|Codons|Existing_variation|DISTANCE|STRAND|FLAGS|VARIANT_CLASS|SYMBOL_SOURCE|HGNC_ID|CANONICAL|MANE_SELECT|MANE_PLUS_CLINICAL|TSL|APPRIS|CCDS|ENSP|SWISSPROT|TREMBL|UNIPARC|UNIPROT_ISOFORM|SOURCE|GENE_PHENO|SIFT|PolyPhen|DOMAINS|miRNA|HGVS_OFFSET|AF|AFR_AF|AMR_AF|EAS_AF|EUR_AF|SAS_AF|gnomADe_AF|gnomADe_AFR_AF|gnomADe_AMR_AF|gnomADe_ASJ_AF|gnomADe_EAS_AF|gnomADe_FIN_AF|gnomADe_NFE_AF|gnomADe_OTH_AF|gnomADe_SAS_AF|gnomADg_AF|gnomADg_AFR_AF|gnomADg_AMI_AF|gnomADg_AMR_AF|gnomADg_ASJ_AF|gnomADg_EAS_AF|gnomADg_FIN_AF|gnomADg_MID_AF|gnomADg_NFE_AF|gnomADg_OTH_AF|gnomADg_SAS_AF|MAX_AF|MAX_AF_POPS|CLIN_SIG|SOMATIC|PHENO|PUBMED|MOTIF_NAME|MOTIF_POS|HIGH_INF_POS|MOTIF_SCORE_CHANGE|TRANSCRIPTION_FACTORS|ClinVar|ClinVar_CLNSIG|ClinVar_CLNREVSTAT|ClinVar_CLNDN"
```

Splitting should be done accordingly to the CSQ fields. Add these headers information to the respective values of CSQ.

```
#Example of VCF file: 
chr1    65636536        rs145651189     A       T       .       .       RS=145651189;dbSNPBuildID=134;SSR=0;GENEINFO=LEPR:3953;VC=SNV;NSM;R3;GNO;FREQ=1000Genomes:0.9986,0.001405|ALSPAC:1,0|ExAC:0.9982,0.001845|GnomAD:0.9998,0.0001996|GnomAD_exomes:0.9984,0.001601|GoESP:0.9996,0.0003844|Korea1K:0.9995,0.0005459|MGP:0.9981,0.001873|Qatari:0.9861,0.01389|SGDP_PRJ:0.5,0.5|TOPMED:0.9997,0.0002645|TWINSUK:0.9995,0.0005394|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9996,0.0004466;CLNVI=.,Illumina_Laboratory_Services\x2cIllumina:294897|Personalized_Diabetes_Medicine_Program\x2cUniversity_of_Maryland_School_of_Medicine:PDMP1158;CLNORIGIN=.,0|1;CLNSIG=.,0|0|3|15|2;CLNDISDB=.,OMIM:614963/MONDO:MONDO:0013992/MedGen:C3554225/OMIM:614963|MedGen:CN239457|MONDO:MONDO:0015967/MedGen:C3888631|MedGen:CN517202|MedGen:CN169374;CLNDN=.,Obesity_due_to_leptin_receptor_gene_deficiency|Monogenic_Non-Syndromic_Obesity|Monogenic_diabetes|not_provided|not_specified;CLNREVSTAT=.,single|single|single|mult|no_criteria;CLNACC=.,RCV000348481.3|RCV000405881.3|RCV000664073.2|RCV001699347.6|RCV001702416.1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.65636536=,NC_000001.11:g.65636536A>T;CSQ=T|missense_variant|MODERATE|LEPR|ENSG00000116678|Transcript|ENST00000349533|protein_coding|20/20||ENST00000349533.11:c.3019A>T|ENSP00000330393.7:p.Ser1007Cys|3188/8211|3019/3498|1007/1165|S/C|Agt/Tgt|rs145651189|1||1||1|SNV|HGNC|HGNC:6554|YES|1|CCDS631.1|ENSP00000330393|P48357.215||UPI000014C37B|P48357-1|NM_002303.6|1|deleterious(0.05)|benign(0.039)|PANTHER:PTHR23036:SF109&PANTHER:PTHR23036||0.0018|0|0|0|0.003|0.0061|0|0.0005814|0.001601|0.0001235|0.000811|0.001791|0|0|0.0003715|0.002132|0.009737|likely_benign&uncertain_significance||1||||||,T|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|LEPR|ENSG00000116678|Transcript|ENST00000371060|protein_coding||||||||||rs145651189|1|1108|1|||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:6554||1|CCDS30740.1|ENSP00000360099|P48357.215||UPI000002AD2A|P48357-2|NM_001003679.3|1|||||0.0018|0|0|0|0.003|0.0061|0|0.0005814|0.001601|0.0001235|0.000811|0.001791|0|0|0.0003715|0.002132|0.009737|likely_benign&uncertain_significance||1||||||,T|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|LEPR|ENSG00000116678|Transcript|ENST00000616738|protein_coding||||||||||rs145651189|1|1127|1|||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:6554||1|CCDS30740.1|ENSP00000483390|P48357.215||UPI000002AD2A|P48357-2|NM_001198689.2|1|||||0.0018|0|0|0|0.003|0.0061|0|0.0005814|0.001601|0.0001235|0.000811|0.001791|0|0|0.0003715|0.002132|0.009737|likely_benign&uncertain_significance||1||||||
```

The output needed is that All this CSQ fields should be splitted into 82 fields and all the other related transcripts information should be filled in that 82 fields only seperated with "," seperated.

I tried to split using vcf2maf tool but it is considering only the 1st 82 fields and giving output.
But, I want all the other transcripts information too.
And also bcftools +split-vep tool also.

Comment: Share your bcftools codes. Did you try https://www.biostars.org/p/9464641/#9464784 ?

Comment: bcftools query -H -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t%ID\t%REF\t%ALT\t%QUAL\t%FILTER\t%INFO/CSQ[\t%TAB] \n' anno.vep.vcf > anno_vep.tsv

bcftools +split-vep -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t%REF\t%ALT\t%CSQ\n' -d -A tab input.vcf

Comment: there is a bcftools plugin named splitvep:  https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/howtos/plugin.split-vep.html

Comment: BCFtools is not working out as required output. 
Some programming help is highly appreciated....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it importing the vcf file and converting it into an R object with library(vcfR):

```
vcf<-read.vcfR("file.vcf")
df <- vcfR2tidy(vcf)
df_fix<-df$fix

df_CSQ <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df_fix$CSQ),'|',fixed=TRUE)))
```